# Web.xml not compiling correctly

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web.xml

I recently tried to convert an Eclipse, Google Appengine Project from java7-java8 since GAE has stopped supporting java7 (or will do in the near future).
The project was working fine before starting the conversion. I am now getting this error when trying to run the project locally:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path: /api/add-batch-shelfsurvey: ApiShelfSurveyBatchServlet,com.imobdev.figjam.ApiShelfSurveyBatchServlet
```

This is the entry in web.xml for that servlet:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApiShelfSurveyBatchServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imobdev.figjam.ApiShelfSurveyBatchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ApiShelfSurveyBatchServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/add-batch-shelfsurvey</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the start of the web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

I've double and triple checked /api/add-batch-shelfsurvey path is unique in web.xml but I still get this error.
The servlet mentioned in the error message changes but none of them have multiple mappings to one path.
I've found these threads that seem similar but aren't actually related:
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/2107
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479865

I don't know if it's relevant but this is my appengine-web.xml file:

```
    <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
        <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
        <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
        <system-properties>
            <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
            <property name="appengine.file.encoding" value="US-ASCII"/>
        </system-properties>
        <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
        <runtime>java8</runtime>
    </appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Changing all <url-pattern> sections to end with '/*' allows me to run the project on my localhost but still fails when I try to deploy to Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the path
`/api/add-batch-shelfsurvey`
might have been registered before try to check all
`<servlet-mapping>`
sections in web.xml and if you have any
`@WebServlet` annotations then check `urlPatterns={"..."}`

If you have two definitions at the same time app server will not know which is the right one.

Comment: Sorry I see I forgot to say, I've double checked that the path is unique. I don't think this is the error.
I was wondering if it was somehow trying to read the web.xml file twice?

Comment: Did you try to comment the section and check if something is responding on that path or changing the path for a second what are the results?

Comment: Good suggestion but yes I did, it just gives the same error with another servlet (there are over 200 servlets in the project).

Comment: Did you tried on clean application server since there may be conflict with previous instance of the appliaction if the app main context is set to `/`. Try if setting of the main context to for example `/a` will change anything.

Comment: I have tried clean the application on the server as well as in eclipse.
I tried changing the app root context, error still occurs.

Comment: Try to add `<public-root>/a</public-root>` under the `<app-engine-web-app>` as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref)

Comment: I think this is due to Jetty change not java change and the servlet 3.1 specs. look [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1000) try to add 3.1 xsd validation to your web.xml and it should point out what is wrong and where in your web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the project to run on the localhost and upload and run on Google App Engine. Unfortunately I don't know exactly what the problem was.
These are the steps I took:
-Removed the /* from all  in web.xml file.
-Changed between version 2.5 xsd and 3.1 xsd several times, running the project on localhost each time.
-Changed back to 2.5 xsd and changed all  back to ending in /*

Project then compiled and ran fine on both localhost and appengine. If anyone knows anything more about why this might happen please let me know.